# How can I trim whitespace by Velocity

Tags: java, whitespace, velocity, removing-whitespace

I have a method called render_something  which can creates a lot of whitespace, for example:

```
<a href="#">#render_something('xxx')</a>
```

The result can be:

```
<a href="#">     

           something that generate from redner_something


              </a>
```

Which actually I want it to be like this:

```
<a href="#">something that generate from redner_something</a>
```

Does velocity has something like this?

```
#trim(#render_something('xxx'))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just read this article on [Velocity Whitespace Gobbling](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityWhitespaceGobbling) which suggests a few work-arounds including [Velocity Whitespace Truncated By Line Comment](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityWhitespaceTruncatedByLineComment).

This basically suggests commenting out line breaks by putting comments at the end of each line. It also suggests not indenting the code in your macros to prevent superfluous (one of my favourite words) spaces occurring.

TBH it's not a great solution but may suit your needs. Simply put `##` at the end of each line in your macro and that will make things a little bit nicer... sort of

Comment: It can be an alternative. Thanks for suggestion. However, my situation cannot use your suggestion because I cannot change render_something.

Answer (score 9):

It seems just java native trim() works.

`$someValue.trim()` works for me

Comment: This does not work for me. I am sure my variable does not contains spaces (forbidden by regex) but it is added after the merge by velocity engine. Adding the trim() does not change anything. However adding the double hash ## works well.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

In the class where you create the VelocityEngine, add a method as follows

```
public String trim(String str) {
    return str.trim()/*.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")*/;
}
```

then add the following to the VelocityContext that you create:

```
    context.put("trimmer", this);
```

and finally in the velocity template do the following

```
<a href="#">$trimmer.trim("#render_something('xxx')")</a>
```

#### Why does it work?

Although the behavior of Velocity is clearly define, it can be a bit tricky to see how it works sometimes. The separate trim()-method is necessary to get the char-sequence from the template into a Java method where you can call the actual trim() on the String. As far as I know there is no trim inside Velocity, but you always can call back to Java with tricks like this one.

The double-quotes are necessary because the #render_something is just a macro, not a function call, this means the results of the statements in the macro are put verbatim into the point where the macro is "executed".

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a while to find a straightforward solution to whitespace gobbling, so here the one I finally came up with. It is inspired from  and Vadzim's answer and this page http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/StructuredGlobbingResourceLoader

The StructuredGlobbingResourceLoader we can find on the website has a complex behaviour and doesn’t get rid of any kind of whitespace, so I modified it to get the simple behaviour: "Delete any whitespace at the beginning of the lines, and add a comment at the end of each line" (which prevents the linebreak evaluation). The filter is applied on the input stream at loading time.

This kind of velocity template

```
#if($value)
    the value is $value
#end
```

is transformed to

```
#if($value)##
the value is $value##
#end##
```

Then if you want to have linebreaks or beginning of line whitespaces, you'll have to put($br,"\n") and put($sp," ") in your context like Vadzim's explained and explicitly use them in your template. This way of doing will allow you to keep indented templates, with maximum control.

take the class from this page http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/StructuredGlobbingResourceLoader
change the extended class to the kind of loader your need (this one uses the webapp loader)
replace the read() method with the code I provide
use the class as your resource loader in your properties. Example for the webapp loader: webapp.resource.loader.class=...StructuredGlobbingResourceLoader

```
public int read() throws IOException {        
    int ch;
    switch(state){
        case bol: //beginning of line, read until non-indentation character
            while(true){
                ch = in.read();
                if (ch!=(int)' ' && ch!=(int)'\t'){
                    state = State.content;
                    return processChar(ch);
                }
            }

        case content:
            ch = in.read();
            return processChar(ch);

        //eol states replace all "\n" by "##\n"
        case eol1: 
            state = State.eol2;
            return (int)'#';

        case eol2:
            state = State.bol;
            return (int)'\n';

        case eof: 
            return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}

//Return the normal character if not end of file or \n
private int processChar(int ch){
    switch(ch){
    case -1:
        state = State.eof;
        return -1;
    case (int)'\n':
        state = State.eol1;
    return (int)'#';
    default:
        return ch;
    }
}
```

Any feedback on my implementation is welcome

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Velocity Whitespace Truncated By Line Comment](https://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityWhitespaceTruncatedByLineComment) one could use block comments instead of line comments for a better looking result:

```
#foreach( $record in $records )#**
    *##if( $record.id == 0 )#**
    *##end
#end
```

With a decent syntax highlighting the comments aren't very obtrusive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my alternative solution to [velocity whitespace gobbling](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityWhitespaceGobbling) that allows tabbing template structure.

Each template text is preprocessed on first load in custom `ResourceLoader`:

```
private String enhanceTemplate(String body) {
    if (!body.startsWith("##preserveWhitespace")) {
        body = body.replaceAll("(##.*)?[ \\t\\r]*\\n+[ \\t\\r]*", Matcher.quoteReplacement("##\n"));
        body = body.trim();
    }
    return body;
}
```

This replaces all new lines and adjustent spaces with just one [commented newline](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityWhitespaceTruncatedByLineComment).

Line breaks and tailing spaces can be inserted explicitly with $br and $sp variables from default context:

```
private static final VelocityContext DEFAULT_CONTEXT = new VelocityContext(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("sp", " ");
    put("br", "\n");
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, I've had to essentially minimize my script like I would js or css. It works well, though it is not as easy for humans to read. Just one other option to eliminate the excess space:

```
<ul class="tabs">#foreach($par in $bodypars)#set( $parLen = ${_MathTool.toInteger($bodypars.size())} )#set( $parLn = $parLen - 1 )#set( $thClass = 'tb'+${parLn} )#set( $thaClass = '' )#if( $foreach.index == 1 )#set( $thClass = ${thClass}+' selected' )#set( $thaClass = ' selected' )#end#if($foreach.index != 0 && $parLen <= $maxTabs)#set ( $btitle = $_XPathTool.selectSingleNode($par,'item-subtitle') )<li class="${thClass}">#if($!btitle && $btitle != '')<a href="#" class="#cleanString($btitle.value.toLowerCase())${thaClass}">$_SerializerTool.serialize($btitle, true)</a>#end</li>#end#end</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard java trim, taking attention to your variable if are a object instead string.

```
$string.trim()  //work fine
$object.trim()  //exception
```

Have a good day!