# can velocity ignore newlines and whitespaces?

Tags: java, whitespace, velocity, template-engine

I want to put newlines and whitespaces in my velocity template to make it more readable. But my output must conform to a format that does not accept newlines and whitespaces.

Can velocity be configured to ignore whitespaces?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594022/how-can-i-trim-whitespace-by-velocity. Seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: the exact oppostie, @Kamikaze_lux. I want to eliminate all whitespace present in the template itself, while keeping whitespace that comes from function calls and variable interpolation, if any.

Answer (score 1):

By default no, but it is possible to do it if you're in control of how the templates are rendered. You can check how [XWiki does this](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/tree/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-rendering/xwiki-platform-rendering-macros/xwiki-platform-rendering-macro-velocity): it [uses](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-rendering/xwiki-platform-rendering-macros/xwiki-platform-rendering-macro-velocity/src/main/java/org/xwiki/rendering/internal/macro/velocity/VelocityMacro.java#L109-113)  a configurable [filter](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-rendering/xwiki-platform-rendering-macros/xwiki-platform-rendering-macro-velocity/src/main/java/org/xwiki/rendering/macro/velocity/filter/VelocityMacroFilter.java) to pre-process the Velocity code to remove white space, and perhaps the [indent filter](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-rendering/xwiki-platform-rendering-macros/xwiki-platform-rendering-macro-velocity/src/main/java/org/xwiki/rendering/internal/macro/velocity/filter/IndentVelocityMacroFilter.java) is the one that suits your needs.

Comment: For informational purposes, space gobbling is now available in Velocity 2.0