# Can I use Velocity templates with InputStreams?

Tags: java, apache-camel, velocity

I'm dealing with large files and I need to wrap XML around a base64 payload. My first naive implementation passed the payload as a `java.lang.String` into the [Velocity template][0], but with large files I want to use `java.io.InputStream` instead.

Here's my template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <AdditonalParameters>
#if( $headers.additionalParameters )
#foreach( $key in $headers.additionalParameters.keySet() )
        <Parameter>
            <Key>${key}</Key>
            <Value>${headers.additionalParameters.get($key)}</Value>
        </Parameter>
#end
#end
    </AdditonalParameters>
    <Content>${body}</Content>
</Request>
```

`$body` can potentially be very large, so I want to avoid using `String` or `byte[]`. Is it possible to pass an `InputStream` as `$body` into my template or can't I use Velocity for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. All it takes is an iteration that prints your `InputString` line by line. Since Velocity lacks a `while`-like construct and only knows about `foreach` loops, the iteration will look like an ugly hack in its most simple implementation:

```
#foreach ($i in [0..100000])
    #set ($line = false)
    #set ($line = $body.readLine())
    #if ($line)
        ${line}
    #else
        #break
    #end
#end
```

Here a very big numeric range is used to simulate an endless loop. The loop will `#break` when no more lines can be extracted from the `InputStream` (the `$body`). A caveat is in the third line:

```
#set (line = $body.readLine())
```

As always in Velocity, the left hand side of the assignment only changes when the value on the right side is not null. Since `$line` will never be assigned a null value, we'll need to pre-set it to `false` (a boolean value, not a string as returned by `readLine`). This way, if `$line` is still `false` after the second `#set`, we know that `readLine` returned null and it's time to exit the iteration.

A problem with this approach are white spaces in the template inserted between lines. There are a few tricks to avoid this ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594022/how-can-i-trim-whitespace-by-velocity)). Also, the `#foreach`hack can be avoided by creating a Java `List` whose `iterator()` method returns an `Iterator` that iterates over the lines of the `InputStream`. This would be less KISS but it would make your code more reusable.

Comment: This looks very promising, will give it a try today.